# Does not export datagridview data to excel vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, foreach, rows, export-to-excel

Im exporting a datagridview to excel, when I export the rows that contains data only for one year it works very well, but when I do for 2 or more years It does not export, my winform collapse.In total, I have 135159 rows to export.

this is my code

```
        Dim exApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

        Dim exLibro As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

        Dim exHoja As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        Try

            exLibro = exApp.Workbooks.Add

            exHoja = exLibro.Worksheets.Add()


            Dim NCol As Integer = dgvDatos.ColumnCount

            Dim NRow As Integer = dgvDatos.RowCount

            'this is to export columns
            For i As Integer = 1 To NCol

                exHoja.Cells.Item(1, i) = dgvDatos.Columns(i - 1).Name.ToString

            Next

        'this is to export all the rows
        For Fila As Integer = 0 To NRow - 1

            For Col As Integer = 0 To NCol - 1

                exHoja.Cells.Item(Fila + 2, Col + 1) = dgvDatos.Item(Col, Fila).Value

            Next
        Next
```

It would be great if you could help me, Thankss!!

Comment: Your code looks good to me.  Are you getting any error messages at all?  Perhaps there's an overflow error when converting data types someplace?  You could try deleting row 2 from your datagrid to see if it gets further or not.

Comment: @Sturgus there's no error message, my winform only stops working. :(

Comment: Try changing your bottom For loop to `For Col As Integer = 0 to 0` and see if it at least exports that column successfully.  If so, then keep adding columns until it crashes.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to see your full `Catch` block.

Comment: the same story @Sturgus, I think there are many records so it takes too long to process.

Comment: I disagree.  135159 records is not a lot to process.  Especially if you've limited it to 1 column.  It's true that it may take a few minutes to export, but it certainly shouldn't crash.  My guess is that if you try to truncate your data to 10 records, you'll have the same problem.  Remember to keep an eye on how many Excel Windows processes are running, as when you do testing on this stuff, it can really eat up your RAM.  Use Task Manager to kill your excess Excel processes until you get the import right.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it helps, but I found using copy+paste in my application a much quicker way to get data into Excel from a `DataGridView`.  That assumes your 135159 records fit on the clipboard...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button4.Click
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


    'FOR HEADERS
    For i = 1 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, i) = DataGridView1.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
        'FOR ITEMS
        For j = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(j + 1, i) = DataGridView1(i - 1, j - 1).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next


    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    MsgBox("You can find the file D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

The path is in the `D:` and the file name is `vbexcel.xlsx`
Note: choosing No will get an error cause it will replace the file with the same file name in the same path. Always choose Yes to replace the existing file.